# How to access cached data of another api slice's endpoint in transformResponse of RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

For example there is books api slice that has listBooks endpoint. Then there is users api slice which has getUserById endpoint.
In getUserById endpoint I need to transform response using cached data of listBooks endpoint assuming that it already has a cache.

I tried using
`const listBooksResult = booksSlice.endpoints.listBooks.select()`
according to this [doc](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-users-data)

but here is the result I got when logging listBooksResult in console:

```
ƒ memoized() {
    var value = cache.get(arguments);
    if (value === NOT_FOUND) {
      // @ts-ignore
      value = func.apply(null, arguments);
      if (resultEqualityCheck) {
        var entries =…
```